# Getting Material Form Fields to Fit within a Flex Box Container?

Tags: javascript, css, angular, angular-material

In this demo the flex container has a max width of `20rem`.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-material-fit-form-fields?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

How do  we get the material form fields to fit within the container?  Currently they overflow.

In other areas of my templates I just apply a class to `mat-form-field` like:

```
u-third-width: { width:33%}
```

Update: The fields in my app were still wrapping because of margins applied to them.  Asked Material to remove the fixed width here:

https://github.com/angular/components/issues/19654

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Provide width to all three `mat-form-field` elements:

```
<mat-form-field style="margin-right:2rem;width:25%">
```

Providing width in percentage will help make them shrink/increase in size with decrease/increase in window size.

Comment: Won't that cause the items to wrap?  I want them all on the same line .... ?

Comment: My bad, it seems I read the question wrong. I edited my answer.

Comment: Except if we use margins on the fields, they still wrap ... I asked  for the fixed width to be removed https://github.com/angular/components/issues/19654

Comment: Don't use margins, use padding

Comment: I see you have given width as 33%. You might want to take the margins into account (I gave 25% considering that).

Answer (score 1):

The fields have fixed widths:

[image]

You need to override the width value:

[image]

Then they'll fit:

[image]

Comment: I added this to `app.component.css` but it still overflows: `mat-form-field-infix {
  width:33% !important;
}`

Comment: @Ole you forgot the dot, this is a CSS class, not an HTML tag

Comment: I tried adding both the class and the element as css selectors.  IIUC the container cannot be a flex box container in order for the width property to be set.